# Java regex - matcher with multiple string clarifications

Tags: java, regex

Input

```
45697B2
```

regex pattern:

```
static Pattern kindCodePattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-z])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

What i do

from the input taken last two char and match single char range a-z, if find remove the last two char else assign an empty

```
kindCode = input.substring(Math.max(input.length() - 2, 0));
        matcher = kindCodePattern.matcher(kindCode);
        Boolean isAvailableKindCode = matcher.find();
        if (isAvailableKindCode) {
            input = input.substring(0, input.length() - 2);
        } else {
            kindCode = "";
        }
```

but some case i want to check the last char only, like if my input was `45697B` then

```
kindCode = input.substring(Math.max(input.length() - 1, 0));
```

doubt:

how can i match both cases in an single matches? is it possible?

or any changes in my pattern?

Comment: I haven’t tested: I’d try something like "[A-Za-z].?$" to match a letter possobly followed by any character at the end of the line. Except for any error this should match "B2" and just "B" in your two examples. You can use `.group()` to take out the substring actually matched from the matcher.

Answer (score 1):

Taking my own word for it, the following method should do what you want:

```
private static final Pattern kindCodePattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z].?$");

public static String findKindcode(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = kindCodePattern.matcher(input);
    boolean isAvailableKindCode = matcher.find();
    if (isAvailableKindCode) {
        return matcher.group();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Given input `"45697B2"` it returns `"B2"`. Given `"45697B"` it yields `"B"`.

`45697BQ` gives `BQ` (not just `Q`), and `456972` gives `null`. Hope you modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks but how can i group the unmatched value like 45697 i want to split into two string string1 = 45697 string2 =B

Comment: `"^(.*?)([A-Za-z].?)$"` and taking out the two groups individually from the matcher?

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect